# ${employee.id} from List in JSP throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I have a JSP page which works fine when showing `List<Employee>` from below method in a `<c:forEach>`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "getAllEmployees", "/" })
public ModelAndView getAllEmployees() {
    // logger.info("Getting the all Employees.");
    List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    return new ModelAndView("employeeList", "employeeList", employeeList);
}
```

Whereas the same JSP throws an exception when showing `List<Employee>` from below method.

```
@RequestMapping("searchEmployee")
public ModelAndView searchEmployee(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {
    // logger.info("Searching the Employee. Employee Names: " + searchName);
    List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.getAllEmployees(searchName);
    System.err.println("Employee count = "+employeeList.size());
    return new ModelAndView("employeeList", "employeeList", employeeList);
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employeeList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(employeeList_jsp.java:358)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employeeList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(employeeList_jsp.java:312)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employeeList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(employeeList_jsp.java:273)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employeeList_jsp._jspService(employeeList_jsp.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Adding the error message would make helping you much easier.

Comment: @Lukehey added error

Comment: And your view next please. Try to include all information, as your mapping obviously works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getAllEmployees(searchName)` method doesn't return a `List<Employee>`, but a `List<Object[]>`. Most likely there's also an "unchecked cast" warning generated by the compiler which you ignored or suppressed.

The evidence is the involvement of `javax.el.ArrayELResolver` in the stack trace. This is only involved when the base of an EL expression is of an array type. If you really had an `Employee` instead of an `Object[]`, then you'd expect `javax.el.BeanELResolver` at the particular stack trace line where the EL expression `${employee.id}` is to be evaluated. As `${employee}` is in your case actually an array, EL will interpret the `id` property as an array index and then tries to parse it as an `Integer`, but failed to do so as you can see in top lines of the stack trace.

To solve this problem, you've 2 options:

1. Fix the `getAllEmployees(searchName)` method to return a **real** `List<Employee>`. Usually, this is to be done by querying the `Employee` entity directly instead of invididual columns/fields.
2. Replace all incorrect `List<Employee>` declarations by `List<Object[]>` and handle it in EL as an object array like so `${employee[0]}`, `${employee[1]}`, etc.