# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/addDepartment.jsp at line 21

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am trying to delete a department from the database in addDepartment.jsp page in my spring mvc application. I do get this error when I try to delete

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/addDepartment.jsp at line 21

18:                 </tr>
19:                 <tr>
20:                     <td><form:label path="departmentName">Department Name:</form:label></td>
21:                     <td><form:input path="departmentName" value="${department.departmentName}"/></td>
22:                 </tr>
23:                 
24:                 <tr>
```

This is the line 21 of the addDepartment.jsp file

```
21:                     <td><form:input path="departmentName" value="${department.departmentName}"/></td>
```

this is the controller for the view that handles the delete function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteDepartment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteCategory(@ModelAttribute("command")  Department department,
            BindingResult result) {
        departmentService.deleteDepartment(department.getDepartmentId());
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("department",  departmentService.getDepartments());
        return new ModelAndView("addDepartment", model);
    }
```

this is the root cause stacktrace from the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "departmentName"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

this is the view of the code that handles the delete from the addDepartment.jsp file

```
<c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${department.departmentId}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${department.departmentName}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="editDepartment?departmentId=${department.departmentId}">Edit</a> | <a href="deleteDepartment?departmentId=${department.departmentId}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Why am I not been able to delete a department name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413698/employee-id-from-list-in-jsp-throws-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-inpu     this was not accepted by the person that asked the question as an answer to his problem and the contents of his question is clearly different from mine

Comment: I read the answers you provided in the question

Comment: My question has already gotten an answer

Comment: So if two problems returns thesame exception makes the other a duplicate?

Comment: From the answer that marked my problem duplicate, the person is trying out something else, me I am trying to make a delete from a jsp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but the exception is not related to the deleteDepartment code but the addDepartment.jsp page, so how have you connected those two together?

Also from the numberFormatException it seems to me as if java is trying to cast the departmentName value into an Integer. Which of course does not make sense because I suppose that you will be feeding a string to this field.

I am noty entirely sure about where the problem is from the code that you have shared but I sense some kind of mixing up selecting the "department" by departmentId or by departnmentName, in order to delete it. Thus the casting from a String value to a number value that throws the exception occurs.

Comment: Also I am not sure that the marked duplicate is indeed the same problem because in the other issue, the guy got a NumberFormatException with input "id" which should be a number, while here we got a NumberFormatException for input "departmentName" which should not be an Integer and thus the exception makes sense.

Comment: This solved my problem with an insight of what is wrong. I was casting a wrong variable

Comment: where does it tell a different story. let me correct myself

Comment: maybe we should begin with controller definition