# I am trying to collect data from database and return its object using String as an parameter in Hibernate

Tags: java

I was trying to collect data from table `ProductInformation` using parameters `ProductId` with following code but all I get is

> unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from com.koshayali.Koshayalinepal.model.ProductInformation where ProductId = :ProductId]

Code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<ProductInformation> getSearchId(String ProductId) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    String sql = "select * from ProductInformation where ProductId = :ProductId";
    Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("ProductId", ProductId);;
    List<ProductInformation> produ = query.list();
    session.close();
    return produ;
}
```

Comment: Also post your `ProductInformation` class. I guess `ProductId` is not the actual class field you are referring to. Also make sure that `ProductId` is String in your class.

Comment: you should lookup HQL syntax

Comment: Replace 'select * from ProductInformation' with 'select p from ProductInformation p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check productId long type or String type first
if database productId is long type convert string to long value

```
 public List<ProductInformation> getSearchId(String ProductId){
        String getproductInfromationQuery = "FROM ProductInformation where ProductId =:ProductId";
            Query queryObj = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery (getproductInfromationQuery);
            queryObj.setParameter("ProductId", ProductId);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<ProductInformation> productList = queryObj.list();
            return productList;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! for your answer it perfectly but it is now talking about "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string" do i have to convert every data to string as in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846044/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-id-for-hibernate" ???

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use * to select everything from database. `FROM class_name` is enough. To have a brief intro into HQL queries look into [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) tutorial.

So, your code should be like this

```
@Transactional
public List<ProductInformation> getSearchId(String ProductId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String sql = "from ProductInformation where ProductId = :ProductId";
    Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("ProductId", ProductId);;
    List<ProductInformation> produ = query.list();
    session.close();
    return produ;
}
```